# Select where tag end in a or b in Terraform data lookup

Tags: amazon-web-services, datasource, terraform

I have 3 subnets. They are named:

`test-subnet-az-a` `test-subnet-az-b` `test-subnet-az-c`

I have a datasource like so:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "test" {
  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "test-subnet-az-*"
  }
}
```

This will return a list including all 3 subnets.

How do I return just the first 2, or those ending in `a` or `b`?

Answer (score 1):

Terraform data sources are generally constrained by the capabilities of whatever underlying system they are querying, so the filtering supported by `aws_subnet_ids` is the same filtering supported by the underlying API, and so reviewing that API (EC2's [`DescribeSubnets`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeSubnets.html)) may show some variants you could try.

With that said, if you can use the data source in a way that is *close enough* to reduce the resultset down to a manageable size (which you seem to have achieved here) then you can filter the rest of the way using a `for` expression within the Terraform language itself:

```
data "aws_subnet_ids" "too_many" {
  vpc_id = "${module.vpc.id}"

  tags = {
    Name = "test-subnet-az-*"
  }
}

locals {
  want_suffixes = toset(["a", "b"])

  subnet_ids = toset([
    for s in data.aws_subnet_ids.too_many.ids : s
    if contains(local.want_suffixes, substr(s, length(s)-1, 1))
  ])
}
```

You can place any condition expression you like after `if` in that `for` expression to apply additional filters to the result, and then use `local.subnet_ids` elsewhere in the configuration to access that reduced set.

I used `toset` here to preserve the fact that `aws_subnet_ids` returns a set of strings value rather than a list of strings, but that's not particularly important unless you intend to use the result with a Terraform feature that *requires* a set, such as the `for_each` argument within `resource` and `data` blocks (which is not yet released as I write this, but should be released soon.)